# How to access nested objects in an array in react native flatlist

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-native, api, react-native-flatlist

Please how do i access the value of `date` which is inside `_embedded` in a nested array like this:

```
[{"id":970,

"title":"Mojekwu v Mojekwu: Facts, Issues &#038; Decision of Court",

"url":"https:\/\/bscholarly.com\/mojekwu-v-mojekwu\/",

"type":"post","subtype":"post",

"_links":{"self":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"https:\/\/bscholarly.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/970"}],

"about":[{"href":"https:\/\/bscholarly.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/post"}],

"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/bscholarly.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/search"}]},

"_embedded":{"self":[{"id":970,"date":"2020-08-01T08:55:39","slug":"mojekwu-v-mojekwu",

"type":"post","link":"https:\/\/bscholarly.com\/mojekwu-v-mojekwu\/",

"title":{"rendered":"Mojekwu v Mojekwu: Facts, Issues &#038; Decision of Court"},
]
```

I am using a flatlist to display them. And I have tried `item._embedded.date` but that did not work for me.

Please help me out.

[This](https://www.bscholarly.com/wp-json/wp/v2/search?search=mojekwu&_embed) is the API link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
_embedded.self[0].date
```